# How can a method call the class which it's a member of in python?

Tags: python, class, parsing, interpreter

I'm learning python and I came across the code for the Fraction below. The Fraction class has an `__add__` method whose return calls the Fraction class. 
(`return Fraction(new_num // common, new_den // common)`).

I don't really get how  a method can call the class it's a part of. I mean the interpreter hasn't even fully finished reading the Fraction class (there's still the `__eq__` method after the `__add__` method) when the `__add__` method calls the Fraction class. What if the `__add__` method wanted to use the classes `__eq__` method when the `__eq__` method is below it?

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, top, bottom):
        self.num = top
        self.den = bottom
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num) + "/" + str(self.den)
    def show(self):
        print(self.num, "/", self.den)
    def __add__(self, other_fraction):
        new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den + \
            self.den * other_fraction.num
        new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den
        common = gcd(new_num, new_den)
        return Fraction(new_num // common, new_den // common)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        first_num = self.num * other.den
        second_num = other.num * self.den
        return first_num == second_num
```

Comment: "I mean the interpreter hasn't even fully finished reading the Fraction class" <- It has already been parsed and executed when you execute `__add__` for the first time. Function bodies are not executed on definition, class bodies are.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation!

Comment: Wait until you learn about recursion...

Comment: [Structure and interpretation of computer programs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs)

Comment: @user3124200 is the question solved?

Answer (score 2):

> I mean the interpreter hasn't even fully finished reading the Fraction class

It has already been parsed and executed when you execute `__add__` for the first time. Function and method bodies are not executed on import time, but class bodies (even nested class bodies) are.

Demo script:

```
class Upper:
    print('Upper')
    class Mid:
        print('Mid')
    def method(self):
        class Low:
            print('Low')
        print('method')
```

Output:

```
$ python3
>>> import demo
Upper
Mid
```

For this reason, it is not an error to refer to the class of a method within that method (because the method is not called during class construction).

On the other hand, you can't access the name of a class while it is still being built within the parts that are executed during import time.

```
>>> class A:
...     print(A)
...
[...]
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

Comment: Is this something you're expected to figure out as you learn the language or would it have helped to take a compiler course to understand something like this?

Comment: @user3124200 Well, you figured it out as you learned the language by asking other Python programmers, didn't you? :) Personally, I learned this from the book Fluent Python. It has evaluation time exercises starting on page 666.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Fraction(new_num // common, new_den // common)
```

What you refer to as "calling the Fraction class" actually creates a new instance of `Fraction` with the given numerator and denominator. If you are familiar with Java, this is equivalent to `return new Fraction(...)`. In Python, we don't use the keyword `new`.

> I mean the interpreter hasn't even fully finished reading the Fraction class

When this line is parsed, the interpreter knows that the `Fraction` class exists, which is sufficient at that time. By the time the line is executed with a call the `__add__()` function on an instance of `Fraction`, the entire `Fraction` class is available to the interpreter.

> What if the `__add__` method wanted to use the classes `__eq__` method when the `__eq__` method is below it?

This is perfectly fine because by the time that the body of the method is executed, the `__eq__` method has been recognized and made available to be called.

Comment: Actually, the interpreter *doesn't* know that there is a `Fraction` class, but it doesn't need to, either. In the body of `__add__`, `Fraction` is just another free variable (since it's not a parameter or a local variable) whose lookup will proceed according to the regular rules once the function is called. At that point, `Fraction` will (or at least, will probably; it doesn't have to!) resolve to the class which at that point is defined. ...

Comment: ... If the body of `Fraction` includes code that *does* attempt to call `__add__` (as a function, since it won't yet actually be a method), then it will likely fail with a `NameError`, as `Fraction` isn't yet bound (at least, not to the class being defined).

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the clarifications. My mental model probably isn't 100% correct. And I had in mind a call to `__add__` from a global context or some other function, not from the body of `Fraction`.